# ES6, any Babel-plugins (Version6) to destructure new Set?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set, babeljs

Following is my Babel config（version: Babel6）

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "useBuiltIns": "usage"
        }
      ],
      "es2015"
      "react",
      "stage-0"
    ],
}
```

It goes right;

But I change the config to remove commonjs support:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "loose": true,
          "modules": false, // modules: no commonjs
          "useBuiltIns": "usage"
        }
      ],
      // "es2015" // delete
      "react",
      "stage-0"
    ],
}
```

Then I found the code get wrong;

```js
// ES6
const se = new Set(['1', '2']);
const arr = [...se]; // arr = ['1', '2'] <- right

// compiler:wrong (without es-2015)
var se = new Set();
var arr = [].concat(se); // arr = [Set] <- wrong

// compiler:right (with es-2015)
var se = new Set();
var arr = [].concat(toConsumableArray(new Set()))  // arr = ['1', '2'] <- right
```

I also use plugin like `transform-es2015-destructuring`, `transform-object-rest-spread`, `syntax-object-rest-spread` but both not work. So is there any method to resolve this question?
to support **destructure Set** similiar with use `es-2015`

expect:

```
"presets": [ /*...*/]
"plugins": ['some-independent plug-ins']
```

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-destructuring

Comment: You are getting this behavior because you explicitly asked for it by passing `"loose": true,`. Remove that and things will work. https://2ality.com/2015/12/babel6-loose-mode.html

Comment: Those confusing appearance is case by config `loose`: true, thanks @loganfsmyth. I won't use `loose` any more. T_T